# Problem with making a youtube bar above recommended videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

[bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrLNw.png)

I'm trying to make this bar in my youtube-copy project. I made the background of the buttons fade away with linear-gradient, but I don't know how to do the same with the text.
html:

```css
#bar-wrap{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 0.6rem;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#bar-wrap .button{
    background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
    color: black;
    width: fit-content;
    height: 2rem;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    padding: 0.4rem;
    cursor: pointer;


    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar-wrap">
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Wszystkie</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Źródło: Ixo Music</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Podobne</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Na żywo</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Ostatnio przesłane</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Obejrzane</div>
</div>
```

I've tried to do linear-gradient on text as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Maybe the buttons/text have no gradient at all and are instead obscured behind an element with a gradient white background?  (The element which contains the `>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a gradient overlay.

```css
#bw1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

#bw1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255 255 255 / 0) 75%, rgb(255 255 255 / 1) 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
}

#bw2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.6em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(211,211,211);
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
#bw2::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
#bw2 {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<div id="bw1">
  <div id="bw2">
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Wszystkie</div>
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Źródło: Ixo Music</div>
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Podobne</div>
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Na żywo</div>
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Ostatnio przesłane</div>
    <div class="button" onclick="barActive(this)">Obejrzane</div>
  </div>
</div>
```